# How do I do multiple counts for each distinct manager ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: my code within SQL]

I just need to figure out how to count the number of buildings each manager manages. I think I just need help for the syntax.

```
-- 5.2.10 Display the MFName, MLName, MSalary, MBdate, and number of buildings that the manager manages for all managers with a salary less than $55,000 

Select MFName, MLName, MSalary, MBDate,     
COUNT(BuildingID) as NoOfBuildManaged    
From Manager, Building
Where Manager.ManagerID = Building.BManagerID    
AND MSalary < 55000    
Group By ManagerID;
```

Comment: When you are grouping, you need to do something with EVERY column in your SELECT statement - either: aggregate columns, or include all non-aggregated columns in your GROUP BY clause.  When asking these sorts of questions, it is always helpful to either include any error messages that you are receiving, or provide some sample data and indicate how your query is not currently providing your expected result

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate the type of data you're working with and the type of results you want; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  building_count AS
(
  SELECT
    BManagerID,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfBuildManaged
  FROM
    Building
  GROUP BY
    BManagerID
)
SELECT
  m.MFName,
  m.MLName,
  m.MSalary,
  m.MBDate,     
  b.NoOfBuildManaged    
FROM
  Manager          AS m
INNER JOIN
  building_count   AS b
    ON m.ManagerID = b.BManagerID    
WHERE
  m.MSalary < 55000    
;
```